# list separator , no comma, no semicolon

Tags: lists, xparse

I'm working on my Liederbuch-Package again and I have developed a meta-data-system to use meta-data in headers and footers.

I currently use `::` as a list separator, but I'm not sure if there isn't a better option. `,` and `;` are impossible because they appear in meta-data (i.e.: `artist = Monty Burns, the evil-doer; Smithers`).

I currently tend to use `&` or `|` instead of `::`.

The main question is: Is this problem already handled anywhere? If yes, how is it done there. If no, do I violate any style rules?

i.e.

```
\begin{Lied}
[title = Als noch Arkadiens gold'ne Tage ::
lithographer = lilypond ::
artist = Test: Test]
{nt}{5}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=1]{CVLB5-AlsNochArkadiensGoldeneTage}
\notentext{\nspace*{11}Als \ns noch \ns Ar \ns* ka \ns* \ns di \ns* ens \ns gold \ns* ne \nspace{15}}
\end{Lied}
```

I can use these values in the header or footer:

```
\LBHead{\textbf{\print{title}} \\ \print{artist} \hfill \print{lithographer}\par}
```

Comment: You should use whatever fits. But mostly a comma is a good list separator since LaTeX support grouping with `{}`. I would definitely not use `&` since that may lead to some errors.

Comment: Why do you have the xparse tag?

Comment: You're a member for more than one year and a 1k rep user, and yet no MWE to start with? The `lists` tag is meant for `TeX` lists or `LaTeX` list environments, not for lists with separators

Comment: @TeXnician Forgot to mention. It uses xparse to decode the meta-data-list. `&` works so far without any flaws.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My package has almost 400 lines in the main file. Since it is not published yet, it would be too much for a MWE. Furthermore it is a styling question.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: I don't agree, however -- you could use a dummy `lied` environment and provide the rest of the splitting code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::` as separator with `expl3`, but you need a couple of tricks. Assuming we are under `ExplSyntaxOn`, you may do

```
\tl_const:Nx \c_maestroglanz_doublecolon_tl { \tl_to_str:n {::} }
```

and when you need to split input at the double colon you can say something like

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV } % needed just once

\seq_set_split:NVn \l_maestroglanz_whatever_seq \c_maestroglanz_doublecolon_tl { #1 }
```

where `#1` stands for the argument to split.

This is because under `\ExplSyntaxOn` the colon is a letter, but saving it with `\tl_to_str:n` we turn it back into an “other character” like it is in the document.

However, this won't work if you need to pass the input to `\keys_set:nn`, because this expects commas as delimiters.

In this case it's probably better to replace commas with `\comma{}` and the double colon with a comma.

Proof of concept.

```
\keys_define:nn { maestroglanz/lied }
 {
  title .tl_set:N = \l_maestroglanz_lied_title_tl,
  lithographer .tl_set:N = \l_maestroglanz_lied_lithographer_tl,
  artist .tl_set:N = \l_maestroglanz_lied_artist_tl,
 }

 \NewDocumentEnvironment{Lied}{O{}mm}
  {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_maestroglanz_lied_options_tl
   \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_maestroglanz_lied_options_tl { , } { \comma{} }
   \tl_replace_all:NVn \l_maestroglanz_lied_options_tl \c_maestroglanz_doublecolon_tl { , }
   \keys_set:nV { maestroglanz/lied } \l_maestroglanz_lied_options_tl
  % other commands for the begin part
 }
 {
  % commands for the end part
 }

% the needed variants
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set:nn { nV }
```